# Java app able to load library but can't find function (visual c++ name mangling?)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

This is my first time using JNI.  I need to call a third-party Visual C++ library from a Java program, so I wrote a wrapper in Visual C++.  The library loads fine, but when I try to call a function from my wrapper library, I get the dreaded UnsatisfiedLinkError.

My wrapper includes the .h file created by javah, and has the following in the .cpp file:

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_Foo_bar (...)

but the library shows (in PE Explorer)
_Java_Foo_bar@32

and my Java code has

public native boolean bar(...) inside class Foo

I suspect the @32 is what's tripping Java up, but I can't figure out how to get rid of it.  I don't know much about compiler/linker settings and the like - I've for the most part been able to get away with defaults, or have had someone else handling that portion of a project.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Try exporting your C++ function [as a C function](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.6):

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_Foo_bar (...)
```

This turns off name mangling.

**Edit**: this is indeed not mangling, but "decoration," which apparently is always done for the `__stdcall` convention that JNI uses. Adding a `.def` file or a `/export` linker argument seem to be the [solution](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13738).

Comment: There is an extern "C" on the function declaration - do I need it on the definition as well?

Comment: I added an extern "C" to the definition and I'm still seeing the same thing in the .dll - is there another switch or something I need to use?  I think the @32 is actually called a 'decoration', not mangling.

Comment: If I interpret the standard correctly, not if the function is declared before it is defined (e.g., the module defining it includes a header that declares it with "C" linkage).

Comment: Either way, it's not working.  I also tried adding a .def file with an alias.  Any other ideas?  I'm really stumped.  Thanks!

Comment: Googled around a bit and devx seems to have the answer. Sun/Oracle's documentation doesn't seem to take this into account.

Comment: It turned out the @32 wasn't the problem - the problem was packages.  I had done javac and javah from the wrong directory.  Stupid examples don't explain how to handle packages properly.